# How to parse a sentence and get output of tags and words for a sentence?

Tags: java, parsing, string-parsing

I am using the below code to parse a sentence and get the output but it's showing an error

```
(method apply in class LexicalizedParser cannot be applied to given types;
  required: List<? extends HasWord>
  found: String
  reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to List<? extends HasWord> by method invocation conversion)
at line parse = (Tree) lp.apply(sent):
```

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import java.util.List;

public class ParserDemo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
        lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});
        String sent="Ohio is located in America";
        Tree parse;
        parse = (Tree) lp.apply(sent);

        List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
        System.out.println(taggedWords);
    }
}
```

What should I do to get the output?

Comment: do you get the error at compile time, or runtime? If it's runtime, make sure the compile time version and runtime version of the library are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error indicates that your string "sent" is not a valid data type for the apply method. You need datatype [LIST](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)! Try putting your "sent" string into a LIST(String) variable, and passing that instead! :)

Comment: could you give the code to solve the problem, its a compile time error thank you

Comment: I will try to give you this, i need to get home first. I will edit my answer as soon as i can.

Comment: Sorry, i realized youre importing special custom classes, I'm not used to downloading such things and setting them up. Try looking at the LIST documentation that i provided a link to. It should show you what to do, or you can google how to use the LIST class, there are lots of examples online. I would think you only have to create a LIST and do something like list.add(sent). :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

You should use `parse` instead of apply.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree;
import java.util.List;

public class ParserDemo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
        lp.setOptionFlags(new String[]{"-maxLength", "80", "-retainTmpSubcategories"});
        String sent="Ohio is located in America";
        Tree parse;
        parse = (Tree) lp.parse(sent);

        List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
        System.out.println(taggedWords);
    }
}
```